# Ping from computer when USB plugs in? Find my USB?

Tags: ping, iphone, ip-address, gps

I lost my USB stick recently, I was just wondering whether it was possible in any way to have it run a program when plugged in to push the computer's IP adress/Coords up to some server anywhere.

Find my iPhone style...

Pure curiosity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was just wondering whether it was possible in any way to have it run
>   a program when plugged in to push the computer's IP address/Coords up
>   to some server anywhere.

Yes it's possible to make a program send the external IP address by e-mail.
But I couldn't find away to run my program automatically!

[image]

According to a biannual Security Intelligence Report from Microsoft,    It appears that a viruses is using the "AutoRun" feature in Windows to    spread itself. Whenever a USB drive is inserted.

But they disable it only for USB flash sticks, It's still working on DVD, External Hard drivers.

Back in the days a company called U3 made smart USB sticks, when you plug it into any computer it will run any program you want, They manage to do that by making the flash stick contain two partitions, the first one contain their program and act like CD player the second as a memory stick.

It's only a program not hardware trick!
So it's still possible somehow.

There is other method Viruses use to run itself by something called [Windows Metafile vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Metafile_vulnerability) 
Windows will try to extract information from the file to display the icon and preview when looking at the folder inside explorer which could be exploited only by previewing the file in explorer.

Or you can hide .exe file into an Image or PDF file and wait the thieve..

Answer (score 1):

No. Autostart isn’t around any more. Good riddance! An iPhone is very different because it communicates with the network itself. A USB drive is just storage.

Of course you could theoretically put a whole computer inside the case that could then also communicate via mobile networks. But, let’s face it: No.

If you want others to return your drive, write your address on it. If you don’t want other to be able to see what’s on the drive, encrypt it.

Comment: If I encrypt it, does it just prompt for a password when you plug it in? Or can I only view it on my machine?

Comment: Hm, there’s two concerns: Mounting the encrypted volume so that you can access it from regular software (requires software to be installed using admin rights) and using it like an encrypted ZIP file (possible without installation, but you need to “extract” the files to use them in regular software and update the file inside the volume afterwards).

Comment: My problem is that I take it to and from school to get past the school's web blocker, so I have to access the files, but I also store other things on there... I'd like to encrypt it, but as you say, I need software that I can't put on their computers...